# Can Facebook's birthday list be expanded to include upcoming birthdays?

Tags: facebook

Is there a way to expand the list of birthdays on Facebook? I use to notice people's birthdays because their names and birthday were listed. Facebook has moved the list up the page, condensed it, and only shows today's birthdays. Is there any way to at least show upcoming birthdays and the persons' birth date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that there is no way to do this.

Answer (score 5):

A Birthday is an event so Facebook treats it like one.

- Go to the sidebar and select Events
- In the sublist click Birthdays
- They will be displayed by Today, This Month.
- Based on privacy you will either get just the date or the date and how old is the individual.
- Clicking the Next Button (Arrow at the bottom pointing right) will go to later Months

Comment: Yes, but I want this list (minus the pictures) to appear in the sidebar like it use to.

Comment: Usability wise, this is how the back and forth nagging between Facebook team and users have resulted to ensure it is easier for someone to create content *now* and receive upcoming (one-two days information) [ref -Facebook Blog](http://blog.facebook.com/blog.php?post=59195087130). Also for someone with 50-100 friends this is fine. But if one were to have 1000-2000 friends and then 50 had a birthday on the same day ? No possible way to show that in a sidebar. The effort to do one extra click (Click->Events Click->Birthdays) versus (Click See All/More) is not that much.

Comment: If you seriously desire a digest of your Facebook Friends Birthday then you should just sign it up as an [email notification](http://www.facebook.com/editaccount.php?notifications) which you would receive every week. Sorry that is the best you can get.

Answer (score 3):

Feb 2012: When you click on Events, you get any upcoming birthdays listed, followed by any upcoming events. To see more birthdays, look at the two buttons at the top right of the section: a button labeled "create event" and a button with a magnifying glass and a down arrow.
[image]

Click on that button, and get a list of other possibilities, one of which is "Birthdays".
[image]

Click on "Birthdays", and you get an expandable list of birthdays.